# Spinner AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener not working

Tags: android, spinner, onitemselectedlistener

I'm using two way data binding on an edit activity, I'm trying to avoid boilerplating and I need to know when the data changed on that activity. I have created a TextWatcher for EditText that works perfectly. Now I want to do the same thing with a Spinner. So I have created a SpinnerWatcher class, referenced it in my model view (POJO) and in my layout. Everything compiles and runs but I am not getting the expected results. The line

```
hasDataChanged = true;
```

never gets executed. I want to specify the setOnItemSelectedListener in the layout file and the logic in the ViewModel, not in the activity.

Here is my SpinnerWatcher class:

```
public abstract class MySpinnerWatcher implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
public abstract void onItemSelected(AdapterView newValue);
}
```

Here is my View Model:

```
public class Diver extends BaseObservable {
...
@Bindable
public AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener getOnSpinnerChanged() {
    return new MySpinnerWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView newValue) {
            // This never gets executed
            hasDataChanged = true;
        }
    };
}
}
```

Here is my layout:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner
android:id="@+id/spinnerGender"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:entries="@array/gender_arrays"
android:prompt="@string/gender_prompt"
app:setOnItemSelectedListener="@{diverdb.getOnSpinnerChanged}"
style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.Underlined"/>
```

Any idea on how to fire that onItemSelected() when changing value in the Spinner?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix my code.

Here is my Spinner Watcher Class:

```
public class MySpinnerWatcher implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
```

}

Here is my View model:

```
@Bindable
public AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener getOnSpinnerChangedDiveType() {
    return new MySpinnerWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            super.onItemSelected(parent, v, position, id);
            // The Hint is in the list at item 0
            if (position != 0 && position + 1 != mDiveTypePosition){
                mHasDataChanged = true;
                // The Hint is in the list at item 0
                DiveType diveType = (DiveType) parent.getAdapter().getItem(position + 1);
                mDiveType = diveType.getDiveType();
            }
        }
    };
}
```

And here is my Layout:

```
<fr.ganfra.materialspinner.MaterialSpinner
                android:id="@+id/spinnerDiveType"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:selectedItemPosition="@={dive.diveTypePosition}"
                app:ms_floatingLabelColor="@color/blue"
                app:ms_multiline="true"
                app:ms_enableFloatingLabel="true"
                app:ms_enableErrorLabel="false"
                app:ms_floatingLabelText="Dive Type"
                app:ms_hint="Dive Type"
                app:setOnItemSelectedListener="@{dive.getOnSpinnerChangedDiveType}"
                app:adapter="@{dive.AdapterDiveType}"
                />
```